# Prove that a transformation of a $\phi$-mixing(or in general mixing) process is still mixing?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, mixing

The general definition of the $\phi$-mixing coefficient is as follows:

$$\phi(\sigma_1,\sigma_2):= \sup\limits_{B \in \sigma_1, A \in \sigma_2, \mathbb{P}(B)>0}\bigg \vert \mathbb{P}(A \mid B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\bigg \vert$$

Now imagine I have some stationary process $\{R_t\}_{t \in \mathbb Z}$;

Then we define: $$\phi(n):=\phi(\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^0,\mathcal{F}_{n}^\infty)$$

where $\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^0$ denotes the sigma algebra generated by $R_0, R_{-1},....$ and $\mathcal{F}_{n}^\infty$ denotes the sigma algebra generated by $R_n R_{n+1},....$;

Now the process is said to be $\phi$-mixing if the number goes to 0 when $n$ goes to infinity; Additionally we might give some convergence speed and say e.g.

$$\phi(n)\leq n^{-1-\epsilon}$$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Now I do some transformation on it; Let's say $\{\vert R_t-m \vert \}_{t \in \mathbb Z}$, where $m$ could be the median;

Also I might do some other transformations e.g. with indicator functions, etc.

Now what I want to show: The transformation is still $\phi$-mixing and maintains the convergence speed; This seems only logical because of some transformation I can only lose information but not gain any;(and losing information means also losing dependence)

But I have no clue how to start a proper proof of it;

Any idea?

---

With transformations I mean something like this:

For what you said, with $R_t'=T(R_t)$ for some measurable function $T$ but also imagine $R_1, ..., R_T$ is a given sample of the process and I want to bootstrap it;
Imagine  we have 20 realizations, so $T=20$;  Now if I bootstrap it e.g. with block length 2, then I pick 10 random natural numbers $\{i_1,...,i_{10}\}$ in $\{1,2,...,20\}$ and my new sample is:

$X_{i_1}, X_{i_1+1}, X_{i_2}, X_{i_2+1}, ..., X_{i_{10}}, X_{i_{10}+1}$

If some index is above 20 I just calculate it modulo 20 (so $X_l=X_{l \pmod{20}}$)

T and the block length can of course vary; Also here it seems logical that we must lose some dependence and therefore the rate of convergence should be the same;

But in none of the two cases (measurable function or with block bootstrap) I am able to show that the rate of convergence maintains or at least the result is still $\phi$-mixing; 
But actually I would need both results to hold

Do you have any idea to show one of the statements? Happy for any idea

---

I'm describing the bootstrap procedure a little bit more in detail: Let $T$ be the amount of realizations;
We choose $f(T)\asymp T^{\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ to be the block length, so it is depending on $T$, e.g. it could be $l:=\lfloor T^{0.2}\rfloor$;

and the number of blocks is then given by $m:=\lfloor T/l \rfloor$. Then the bootstrap sample might have a sample size being less than $T$ but it shouldn't make any problems and we can assume that the bootstrap sample also has size $T$;

More important is the observations that both, the number of blocks as well as the block length go to infinity when T goes to infinity;

The procedure is the same as I described before; take $m$ random numbers $\{i_1,...,i_m\}$ from the set $\{1,...,T\}$ randomly with equal probability and set the bootstrap sample as:

$X_{i_1},X_{i_1+1}, ...,X_{i_1+(l-1)}, X_{i_2},..., X_{i_2+(l-1)},..., X_{i_m},..., X_{i_m +(l-1)}$;

For an index exceeding $T$ we just calculate the index modulo $T$ as usual;

Also here it seems logical that the bootstrap sample should have the same convergence rate; Maybe for my purposes it would be enough to show that at least it is still $\phi$-mixing;

Can I just use this very very simple argument? "Since the block length goes to infinity and every block itself is $\phi$-mixing if we consider it as an own sample, also the bootstrap sample must be $\phi$-mixing"
Is this a sufficient argument to prove at least that the dependence goes to zero? Not really sure about that to be honest...

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what kinds of transformations you mean?   Do you mean looking at processes  like $R_t' =T(R_t)$, for some measurable $T:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, or something more complex?

Comment: Please check my extension of the question for what I want

Comment: Sorry to take so long to respond. I'm still not completely sure of what you want.  If $T:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$ and $R'_t = T(R_t, R_{t-1}, \ldots , R_{t-k+1})$, then the $R_t'$ process is $\phi$-mixing because any event involving $R'_t$ is already in $\mathcal F_{-\infty}^t$.  (You might have to replace $\phi(n)$ with $\phi(n-k)$ here and there, but that can hardly affect asymptotics.)   What really worries me, however, is your mentioning $T=20$ in the context of *mixing*, a subject that addresses what happens with more data over longer time spans.

Comment: Sorry for taking even much longer now for my answer - there has been a night in between for me and then couldn't immediately check for your answer; First of all: Thank you very much for your answer - this is already helping a lot. But do you mind continue talking about it? With your comment you showed that if $\{R_t\}_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is $\phi$-mixing with some convergence rate and if for any meas. function $T:R_t \to R_t'$ it holds that $\{T(R_t)\}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is $\phi$-mixing with the same convergence rate, then it also holds for any meas. function $T:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$

Comment: However it is not yet proven that for any measurable function $T: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $T: R_t \to R_t'$ the stochastic process $\{T(R_t)\}_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is $\phi$-mixing with the same convergence rate;  Or am I wrong? It seems obvious but I don't know how to properly prove it; With the bootstrap: Check another extension of my question

Comment: If $R'_t = T(T_t)$, any event involving $R_t'$ is already an event involving $R_t$.  The field generated by $R_0', R_{-1}',\dots$ is a sub-field of the field generated by $R_0, R_{-1},\dots$.  The $\phi'$ for the $R_t'$ process is upper-bounded by the original  $\phi$.  For the $k-$block version, you have to shift time by $k-1$ steps, so $\phi'(t)\le\phi(t+k)$, for the same reasons.

Comment: So easy - thank you :-) And what about the bootstrap?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63371/discussion-between-kimchi-lover-and-j-doe).